# Insert list items dynamically based on conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, dom

```
$('#mydiv').append(
{
   '<li><span><label>'+'Name'+'</label></span>
<span><label>'+data.Name+'</label></span></li>',

//if array is empty no need to insert the element.

$.each(data.dependent, function (i, item) {
'<li><span><label>'+'Depenedents'+'</label></span>
<span><label>'+item.text()+'</label></span></li>'
   });
},
 '<li><span><label>'+'last Name'+'</label></span>
<span><label>'+data.LName+'</label></span></li>'
);
```

data is an input element which has below properties.

name:"john"
dependent[1]:"James","Jessy"
LName:"Jose"
I have tried append, insertBefore and many more inbuilt jquery methods to insert li tag based on condition. Unfortunately the conditioned li items are not getting inserted.

Comment: You have too many stray single quotes,

Comment: I have corrected them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is full of syntax error as you are not supplying the valid content, See docs [`$.fn.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
$('#mydiv').append('<li><span><label>' + 'Name' + '</label></span> <span> <label> ' + data.Name + ' </label></span> </li>');

//if array is empty no need to insert the element.
if (data.dependent.length) {
    $.each(data.dependent, function(i, item) {
        $('#mydiv').append('<li><span><label>' + 'Depenedents' + '</label></span> <span > <label> ' + item.text() + ' </label></span></li>');
    });
}

$('#mydiv').append('<li><span><label>' + 'last Name' + '</label></span> <span> <label> ' + data.LName + ' </label></span> </li>');
```